# Issue with Electron ipcRenderer.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

I have an Electron app. It sends via a ipcRenderer.send in renderer.js a download event to an ipcMain.on listener in index.js:

renderer.js:

```
for (var i=0; i < data3.projects.length; i++) {
    var project = data3.projects[i]; 

    for (var j=0; j < project.files.length; j++) {
        var file = project.files[j];
        async function downloadFunction(file) {
            await ipcRenderer.send("download", {
                url: file.url,
                location: "/Users/Marc/GreenPool/" + project.projectId + "/files/"
            })
            console.log("downloaded " + file.url);
        }
        await downloadFunction(file);
    }
}
```

index.js:

```
ipcMain.on("download", function (event, info) {
     console.log(info.location);
     download(mb.window.webContents, info.url, {directory:info.location});
});
```

So it is supposed to download (thanks to electron-dl npm package) all the files under project.files, and save them under info.location.

When there is only one project under data3.projects array, it works, the files get downloaded and stored under "/Users/Marc/GreenPool/" + project.projectId + "/files/".

But when there is more than one value in data3.projects array, it only saves the downloaded files of one of the data3.project, not of the others:

One has the files:

[image]

One doesn't:

[image]

We can see on the first picture that one of the files is duplicated. I think it shows that the issue has to do with the fact that after writing the first files in the first folder, it somehow still thinks that it is in this one when starting to write the second files (we can see it with file compute2Numbers(1).js being a duplicate because it is in the wrong folder).

And the log of console are logic:

index.js:

```
/Users/Marc/GreenPool/qjggnatri/files/
/Users/Marc/GreenPool/qjggnatri/files/
/Users/Marc/GreenPool/qjggnatri/files/
/Users/Marc/GreenPool/qjggnatri/files/
/Users/Marc/GreenPool/z9g7_a1qa/files/
/Users/Marc/GreenPool/z9g7_a1qa/files/
/Users/Marc/GreenPool/z9g7_a1qa/files/
/Users/Marc/GreenPool/z9g7_a1qa/files/
```

renderer.js:

[image]

[image]

It seems like it is an asynchronous issue. But I have wrapped the queries in an async await function to prevent the two download events from overlapping each other. And the logs of the console show it: first the files of the first value in data3.projects array are downloaded, then the files of the second value in data3.projects array are downloaded.

So how can I make it happen that the files get saved in the proper folder?